# throw-expressions in ternary operator

Tags: c++

According to ISO/IEC 14882:2011, we can't use throw-expressions both in second and third operands of ternary operator:

> 5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond]
>
> 2 If either the second or the third operand has type void, then the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and
>   function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the
>   second and third operands, and one of the following shall hold: — The
>   second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression
>   (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and is a prvalue. —
>   Both the second and the third operands have type void; the result is
>   of type void and is a prvalue. [ Note: This includes the case where
>   both operands are throw-expressions. —end note ]

Why both Comeau compiler and gcc allows this code?

```
int main()
{
   true ? throw 0 : throw 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully, the standard doesn't prohibit it, it even refers to it in the note.

Comment: can we throw classes too? maybe a file? I mean the variable of the file :)

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık - you can't throw classes. You can throw **objects** of class type.